# How to get registered EventListener for Android UI component at runtime

Tags: android, event-listener, android-testing

I'm writting a testing program for a bunch of Android app. I plan to first get all the view objects (which is not instance of ViewGroup) on the screen, and fire events against them(by robotium or sdk provided method). The issue is, I don't know what kind of EventListener registered to those view objects. I try to fire CLICK to all those objects, but there are quite a lot of other event handlers for LongCLICK, flip, doubletap [etc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html). So is there anyway I can get registered EventListener for Android UI component at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Hi David you can use listener for button is setOnClickListener(). But if you want listener for CheckBox you can use setOnCheckedChangeListener()/setOnClickListener() to identify the status of CheckBox.Similarly you have to implement listener for View according to your requirement/use case.
If you want to implement listener for button you can do it in the following way.

```
 Button b= (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourBtnName);
 b.setOnClickListener(BtnListener);

 private OnClickListener  BtnListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Here you can perform your stuff
   }
  }
```

Comment: Hi! Akshay, What I want to do is to check at runtime, for instance, in testing program, that if a certain view has registered listener or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Hierarchy Viewer tool that comes with Android's SDK? I think Hierarchy Viewer gives that information.